# wkHTMLtoPDF memory corruption and AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, access-violation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the wkHTMLtoXSharp wrapper to call the wkHTMLtoPDF library on Windows 2008 R2.   It’s all working great with one exception. I’m calling the wrapper from a C# windows service.  On the first run the conversion works flawlessly.  On subsequent runs I get memory corruption or AccessViolationException.  The only way to fix it is to kill the process that the DLL is running in.  That seems to reset the underlying issue.  Any clue how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Debugging heap corruption in code you didn't write, written in a language you are unfamiliar with is very unjoyful.  Especially given the size of the codebase.  If you can't get help from the library authors then ditch it and try something else.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I'm getting help from the library authors.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure Zubrowka.  I tried every trick I'm familiar with to overcome the memory corruption without much luck.

Given that the first run was working flawlessly, I decided to wrap the PDF call in an executable and called the CommandLine executable via ProcessStartInfo. This is working just fine for me.  I prefered not to cause as much context switching, however, it's the lesser of both evils.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. I ended up with a similar solution as rggazarian by using the 
wkhtmltopdf package from [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-installer.exe&can=2&q=)
And then this code

```
 public static void GenerateNewStylePDF(string domain, string url, string applicationPath)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = applicationPath + "\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe",
                                Arguments = domain + url + " \"" + applicationPath + "export.pdf\"",
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                RedirectStandardError = true
                            };
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
        var s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var e = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```